# Is it possible to combine columns on a table with max width?

Tags: html, css

I [have a table](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/xjkaY/)

```
<table style="width:5em">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>Here be some </td><td>#</td><td>#</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is it possible to expand the text `Here be some` across all columns?  I do not care if `<td>#</td>` is removed, but removing the columns does not appear to help.

The problem is that the table has enough row width to fit the content, but only if the first column fills the entire row's width.

Essentially, is it possible to emulate what we can do with Excel's merge cell ability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`colspan`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#attr-tdth-colspan)

```
<table style="width:5em">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="3">Here be some </td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<table style="width:5em">
<tbody>
    <tr><td colspan=3>Here be some </td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `colspan`

```
<table style="width:5em">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td colspan="3">Here be some </td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```